# Find the first shared node in linklist C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create this function that will return the first shared node of two linklists. But the there is a bug I can't fix even after trying for a long time.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stack>
#include "LinkList.hpp"
 using namespace std;

void FindFirstSharedNode(ListNode *pNode1, ListNode *pNode2, ListNode *pShared)
{
    stack<ListNode> stack1;
    stack<ListNode> stack2;

    if(pNode1!=nullptr && pNode2!=nullptr)
    {
        while(pNode1!=nullptr)
        {
            stack1.push(*pNode1);
            pNode1=pNode1->m_pNext;
        }
        while(pNode2!=nullptr)
        {
            stack2.push(*pNode2);
            pNode2=pNode2->m_pNext;
        }
        ListNode *node1=nullptr;
        ListNode *node2=nullptr;
        while(!stack1.empty() && !stack2.empty())
        {
            (*node1)=stack1.top();  //Xcode bug: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
            (*node2)=stack2.top();
            if(pNode1==pNode2)
            {
                *pShared=*pNode1;
                stack1.pop();
                stack2.pop();
            }

        }
        cout<<pShared->m_nKey<<" ";
```

I don't see where the problem is?
Can someone tell me?
Much appreciated.

Comment: what is `ListNode` ? how you call from main ?